# React fetch returns an empty value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jsx

Im trying to get json data from an api using react and insert it into an html page.
Here's the function:

```
function GetApiContent() {
  let value = fetch(api2)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results.title)

      return {
        title: results.title,
        date: results.date,
        hdurl: results.hdurl,
        explanation: results.explanation,
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{value.title}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Api test</h1>
          <Hola message="hello" />
        </header>

        <GetApiContent />
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Console log works and returns title but when i return it in the function it shows the h3 tag [empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sp1g.jpg) in the web page.

Comment: That's because when you return your h3 block, the fetch call (which is asynchronous) has likely not completed yet, so value.title is not set. Try putting it all within the `then` handler.

Comment: Actually the implementation seems correct.  Can you put console before the return of 'GetApiContent' method and check whether the variable value is formed correctly

Comment: It seems value is not formed so i think Jaxx is correct. I don't understand what you mean by putting it all in the .then, l tried to return the html code inside the .then but i get the error: Objects are not valid as a React child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch` is an asynchronous, Promise-based operation and it doesn't return value right away. It returns Promise. This is why your code is not working. You're basically trying to display Promise's `value` property which is not what you want. You want to wait for the Promise to resolve (in other words: for fetch to finish request and resolve to the response). You can do it that way to display value from your api:

```
const getApiContent = () => fetch(api2).then(response => response.json())

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getApiContent()
      .then(result => this.setState({ title: result.title }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Api test</h1>
          <Hola message="hello" />
        </header>
        {!!this.state.title && (
          <div>
            <h3>{this.state.title}</h3>
          </div>
        )}
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and got this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null: Shouldn't componentDidMount() return something?

Comment: @Mikiko9 nope. This is only a callback method with return type `void`. In which line error occurs?

Comment: in -> {!!this.state.result && (

Comment: @Mikiko9 I've edited the code in my answer. Please try it out.

Comment: Same error but with title instead of result. What exactly is 'this.state' referring to? Does setState bound an object called state to the class?

Comment: @Mikiko9 state is an inherent part of React's components and are built in. Can you paste a link with the WHOLE code in your file? You can use https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Mikiko9 you haven't used the code the way it is in my answer ;) That's why you have these errors. You forgot to declare `state` at the beginning of `App` component. You can see here that this code works: https://codesandbox.io/s/jvlj08zopv

Comment: Yeah for some reason i didn't see the declaration. Now it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

lukaleli is right. You should get familiar with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Another option for you would be use [`async` & `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
async function GetApiContent() {
  let value = await fetch(api2)
  ...
```